# Android App Crashed

Tags: android

My app was working well but suddenly in emulator my app is crashed but i didn't made any changes in the code

for reference

```
04-12 09:41:05.079: W/ActivityManager(879): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{b5aaca48 com.bostonmediatech.gayatrimantra/.Main}
04-12 09:41:05.079: W/ActivityManager(879): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{b5c6ea90 com.bostonmediatech.gayatrimantra/.Home}
04-12 09:41:06.449: I/ActivityManager(879): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.bostonmediatech.gayatrimantra/.Main} from pid 1008
04-12 09:41:06.449: W/WindowManager(879): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21005
04-12 09:41:06.459: D/dalvikvm(1466): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
04-12 09:41:06.459: D/dalvikvm(786): GC_EXPLICIT freed 35K, 4% free 8982K/9283K, paused 0ms+4ms
04-12 09:41:06.470: D/dalvikvm(786): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 4% free 8982K/9283K, paused 1ms+0ms
04-12 09:41:06.470: D/dalvikvm(786): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 4% free 8982K/9283K, paused 0ms+0ms
04-12 09:41:06.470: I/ActivityManager(879): Start proc com.bostonmediatech.gayatrimantra for activity com.bostonmediatech.gayatrimantra/.Main: pid=1466 uid=10039 gids={}
04-12 09:41:06.479: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(879): setKernelCountSet(10039, 1) failed with errno -2
04-12 09:41:06.479: D/dalvikvm(1466): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 67K, 3% free 9021K/9283K, paused 0ms
04-12 09:41:06.479: I/dalvikvm-heap(1466): Grow heap (frag case) to 9.450MB for 614412-byte allocation
04-12 09:41:06.509: D/dalvikvm(1466): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 4% free 9621K/9927K, paused 0ms+1ms
04-12 09:41:06.571: D/gralloc_goldfish(1466): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
04-12 09:41:06.619: I/ActivityManager(879): Displayed com.bostonmediatech.gayatrimantra/.Main: +170ms (total +12s176ms)
04-12 09:41:06.629: W/InputManagerService(879): Starting input on non-focused client com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@b5c2dfa0 (uid=10012 pid=1008)
04-12 09:41:07.207: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(879): setKernelCountSet(10012, 0) failed with errno -2
04-12 09:41:07.789: W/ThrottleService(879): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
04-12 09:41:07.789: E/ThrottleService(879): Error reading data file
04-12 09:41:08.689: I/ActivityManager(879): START {act=com.bostonmediatech.gayatrimantra.CLEARSCREEN cmp=com.bostonmediatech.gayatrimantra/.Home} from pid 1466
04-12 09:41:08.689: W/WindowManager(879): Failure taking screenshot for (180x300) to layer 21010
04-12 09:41:08.699: D/dalvikvm(1466): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4K, 3% free 9640K/9927K, paused 3ms
04-12 09:41:08.699: I/dalvikvm-heap(1466): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.054MB for 614412-byte allocation
04-12 09:41:08.719: D/dalvikvm(1466): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 4% free 10240K/10567K, paused 0ms+0ms
04-12 09:41:08.731: D/AndroidRuntime(1466): Shutting down VM
04-12 09:41:08.731: W/dalvikvm(1466): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb508f180)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.bostonmediatech.gayatrimantra/com.bostonmediatech.gayatrimantra.Home}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class android.widget.ListView
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:606)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at com.bostonmediatech.gayatrimantra.Home.onCreate(Home.java:26)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     ... 11 more
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:586)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     ... 24 more
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.widget.AdapterView.setOnClickListener(AdapterView.java:761)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3018)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:385)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.widget.AdapterView.<init>(AdapterView.java:234)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.widget.AbsListView.<init>(AbsListView.java:734)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:141)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     at android.widget.ListView.<init>(ListView.java:137)
04-12 09:41:08.731: E/AndroidRuntime(1466):     ... 27 more
04-12 09:41:08.731: W/ActivityManager(879):   Force finishing activity com.bostonmediatech.gayatrimantra/.Home
04-12 09:41:08.759: D/dalvikvm(879): GC_CONCURRENT freed 347K, 12% free 11209K/12615K, paused 0ms+1ms
04-12 09:41:09.199: I/Process(879): Sending signal. PID: 1466 SIG: 3
04-12 09:41:09.199: I/dalvikvm(1466): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-12 09:41:09.199: I/dalvikvm(1466): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-12 09:41:09.239: W/ActivityManager(879): Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{b5c736d0 com.bostonmediatech.gayatrimantra/.Home}
04-12 09:41:09.239: I/Process(879): Sending signal. PID: 1466 SIG: 3
04-12 09:41:09.239: I/dalvikvm(1466): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-12 09:41:09.239: I/dalvikvm(1466): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-12 09:41:09.249: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(879): setKernelCountSet(10012, 1) failed with errno -2
04-12 09:41:09.301: W/NetworkManagementSocketTagger(879): setKernelCountSet(10039, 0) failed with errno -2
04-12 09:41:09.323: D/dalvikvm(1008): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2466K, 29% free 17654K/24647K, paused 5ms
04-12 09:41:09.499: D/dalvikvm(1008): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1766K, 28% free 17895K/24647K, paused 0ms+0ms
04-12 09:41:09.529: D/dalvikvm(1008): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1568K, 26% free 18277K/24647K, paused 17ms
04-12 09:41:09.531: D/dalvikvm(1008): GC_CONCURRENT freed 310K, 26% free 18312K/24647K, paused 1ms+1ms
04-12 09:41:10.199: I/Process(1466): Sending signal. PID: 1466 SIG: 9
04-12 09:41:10.199: I/WindowManager(879): WIN DEATH: Window{b5be9ae0 com.bostonmediatech.gayatrimantra/com.bostonmediatech.gayatrimantra.Main paused=true}
04-12 09:41:10.199: I/ActivityManager(879): Process com.bostonmediatech.gayatrimantra (pid 1466) has died.
04-12 09:41:10.269: W/InputManagerService(879): Got RemoteException sending setActive(false) notification to pid 1466 uid 10039
04-12 09:41:19.301: W/ActivityManager(879): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{b5c0f358 com.bostonmediatech.gayatrimantra/.Main}
04-12 09:41:19.301: W/ActivityManager(879): Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{b5c736d0 com.bostonmediatech.gayatrimantra/.Home}
```

Comment: add xml code of your layout in question, These logs show that you have a problem in layout file, line 8.

Answer (score 2):

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead

This is the exception, occured because you have set onClickListener for ListView but you should set onItemClickListener.

And also post your code to identify other issues.

And also make sure that it is of `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()`

Answer (score 2):

Remove onClick or onItemClick from layout